# Ngrx reset form input after action completes

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have a dumb component that contains an input. When the user clicks on the add button, I'm emitting Output with the text. The smart component fetches the event and dispatch to the store.

How can I reset the input value after the action completes?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'add-post',
  template: "<input #post>
             <button (click)="add.next(post.value)">Add</button>
"
})
export class AddPostComponent {
  @Output() addPost = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to implement a reset-method and directly access the component in its parent component:

```
export class AddPostComponent {
    @ViewChild()
    post;

    public reset() {
        this.post.value = "";
    }

    // ...rest
}
```

and in the parent-template:

```
<add-post #addPost (addPost)="..."></add-post>
```

and in the parent-component:

```
class ParentComponent {
    @ViewChild()
    addPost: AddPostComponent;

    actionCompleteHandler() {
        this.addPost.reset();
    }

}
```

---

Another way would be to define a dummy-input:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'add-post',
  template: "<input #post>
             <button (click)="add.next(post.value)">Add</button>
"
})
export class AddPostComponent {
  @ViewChild()
  post;

  @Input()
  public set reset(value: boolean) {
      if (value === true) {
          this.post.value = "";
      }
  }

  @Output() addPost = new EventEmitter();
}
```

And then use it in combination with `async`:

```
<add-post [reset]="actionComplete$ | async"></add-post>
```